# Using Azure CLI Get the 'principalId' value of an Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

```
PS /home/ian> az network application-gateway identity show --gateway-name "xxx-inf-abc-wag" --resource-group "network-xxx"
{
  "principalId": null,
  "tenantId": null,
  "type": "userAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": {
    "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX-80b8-4447-b2a6-XXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/network-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/dev-gpp-wag-mi": {
      "clientId": "DDDDDDDDD-eb2e-4836-898a-DDDDDDDDD",
      "principalId": "UUUUUUUUUU-b7c8-43d2-80a2-UUUUUUUUUU"
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to retrieve the value of the field 'principalId' from the above json returned from running 'az network application-gateway identity show'.

I think I need to add "--query ...something". I tried "--query .principalId" but this doesn't work. I know there's something wrong with my syntax for "--query" but don't know how to solve it ?

Comment: Which one do you need, the `principalId` that is null or the one nested under `userAssignedIdentities`?

Answer (score 1):

The `az network application-gateway identity show` works with the following query expression

`$id=$(az network application-gateway identity show -g MyResourceGroup --gateway ag1 --query 'userAssignedIdentities."/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX-80b8-4447-b2a6-XXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id1".principalId' -o tsv)`

**Explanation**

The `az network application-gateway identity show -g MyResourceGroup --gateway-name ag1` gives the below output:

```
{
  "principalId": null,
  "tenantId": null,
  "type": "userAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": {
    "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX-80b8-4447-b2a6-XXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id1": {
      "clientId": "DDDDDDDDD-eb2e-4836-898a-DDDDDDDDD",
      "principalId": "UUUUUUUUUU-b7c8-43d2-80a2-UUUUUUUUUU"
    }
  }
}
```

Since the key `/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX-80b8-4447-b2a6-XXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id1` contains forward slashes and a dot character (which are special characters), it has to be escaped.

Hence, the key should be quoted with double quotes

Comment: Your answer is quite recent, but I don't get this work. I am running it with Powershell by surrounding the managed identity ID path with double quotes as you have in the query expression (basically I copied your command and replaced the path), but when executed I get error message `ERROR: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: 'userAssignedIdentities./subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-f4XX-4aXX-91XX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/rg-p-network/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id-agw.principalId'`. Are you also using Powershell and does your example still work at your side?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using another az command...

$id = $(az ad sp list --display-name "XXX-abc-wag-mi" --query [0].id --output tsv)